# What does it mean when a character has left on a quest of personal hardship and pain?

Tags: darkest-dungeon

So I just got back from a quest, and and I got a message that one of my explorers (Dismas) has "left on a quest of personal hardship and pain".  He's got a question mark over his avatar, and is not able to go on quests.

[image]

What does this mean? When will he return?

Answer (score 8):

This can happen when characters are sent to stress relief (Abbey, Tavern). Your character will return after an undetermined period of time. Anecdotal evidence, but my experience is that characters with higher stress tend to go on more journeys of self-discovery.

Comment: are there any benefits/drawbacks aside from the character being unavailable to use?

Comment: Well, it's possible that the character could gain Quirks (positive and negative) when they return.

Comment: I had a similar issue with a crusader "had left the abbey for an unknown location". There was a red question mark next to his portrait, and he showed up again 2 weeks later refreshed. Selfish bastard!